# Imported packages do not work with my package in R for some functions?

Tags: r

I built my own package. I imported the most important package that I need them in my package. In these packages there are some functions are not exported by the package (I did not find them in the namespace of the package). I need these functions. When I call them, I get an error that those funciton are not found. So, How I can solve this problem. Also, how does these packages uses this functions inside their packages without using @export!! any help please?

based on the answer:

I understand I do it like this inside my `R` code: I need the following function:

```
args <- preproc(c(as.list(environment()), call = match.call()),
               check_matrix,
                check_fammat,
                check_parmat,
                check_par2mat)
           list2env(args, environment())
```

Then I must do like this:

```
VineCopula:::preproc()
```

Then how to call `args`?

Comment: Just put the arguments inside the braces as always. `VineCopula:::preproc(c(as.list(environment()),...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call non exported functions with

```
packagename:::functionname()
```

It is however not recommended to do that since those functions might not be supported in future versions of packages.

If you want to use a non exported function from your own library inside your own library, you can just use `functionname()` altough some package developers still prefer `packagename:::functionname()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do I have to do that inside my function. e.g.`my_fun(arguments){ packagename:::functionname()}`

Comment: Yes, you do that in your `R` code. The `NAMESPACE` file does not need to be changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I spent hours to find the solution.

Comment: sorry for my comment: Can I still use:` args <– packagename:::functionname()` because I need args in other code?